# Backend freezing up after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React app using Axios, Express, Node, and an Oracle SQL database. In my frontend, I'm trying to switch from hard coding the query parameters to using a form. For that part I'm trying to use `useState` to implement updating the parameters to whatever the user input is. For reasons I cannot figure out, switching from hard coding the parameters to implementing `useState` is causing my backend to freeze up and I have to kill/restart it.This is my frontend code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Query3 = () => {
    const [queryInfo, setQueryInfo] = useState([]);
    const [year1, setYear1] = useState("");
    const [year2, setYear2] = useState("");
    const [area1, setArea1] = useState("");
    const [area2, setArea2] = useState("");
    const [itemName, setItemName] = useState("");
    const queryId = 'query3';

    // const year1 = '1990';
    // const year2 = '1999';
    // const area1 = 'United States of America';
    // const area2 = 'Europe';
    // const itemName = 'Apples';

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadQueryInfo = async () => {
            setArea1("Eurpoe");                   // These set methods are placed here for testing purposes only.
            setArea2("United States of America"); // They will eventually go in html that is returned.
            setYear1("1990");
            setYear2("1999");
            setItemName("Apples");
            const response = await axios.get(
                `http://localhost:5000/${queryId}`, 
                {params: {
                    area1,
                    area2,
                    year1,
                    year2,
                    itemName
                }});
            const newQueryInfo = response.data.rows.at(0).at(1);
            setQueryInfo([newQueryInfo]);
        }
        loadQueryInfo();
    }, [area1, area2, itemName, queryId, year1, year2]);

    return (
        <>
        <p>This is the query result (Query 3): {queryInfo} </p>
        </>
    );
}

export default Query3;
```

I've reverted back to a working version several times as part of trying to narrow the issue down. That is why the form isn't present.

The following is my endpoint. I don't think the issue is in there but I'm adding it just in case.

```
app.get('/query3', (req,res) => {
    async function fetchQuery3() {
        try{
            const connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
            
            oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_ARRAY;
            const area1 = req.query.area1;
            const area2 = req.query.area2;
            const year1 = req.query.year1;
            const year2 = req.query.year2;
            const itemName = req.query.itemName;

            const query = 
            `select a1.a1yr year1,
                    a1.area1 area1,
                    a1.ratio1 area1_ratio,  
                    a2.a2yr year2,
                    a2.area2 area2,
                    a2.ratio2 area2_ratio
             from (
                 select c1.area_name area1, c1.year a1yr, c1.value hectares, value_2 tonnes, c1.value/value_2 ratio1
                 from crop_data c1
                     inner join
                         (select c2.year c2_yr, c2.area_name c2_country, c2.item_name, c2.unit unit_2, c2.value value_2
                         from crop_data c2
                         where c2.year between ${year1} and ${year2}
                         and c2.unit = 'ha'
                         and c2.item_name = '${itemName}'
                         and c2.area_name = '${area1}')
                     on c1.year = c2_yr and c1.area_name = c2_country
                 where c1.year between ${year1} and ${year2}
                 and c1.unit = 'tonnes'
                 and c1.item_name = '${itemName}'
                 and c1.area_name = '${area1}'
             ) a1
             inner join (
                 select c1.area_name area2, c1.year a2yr, c1.value hectares, value_2 tonnes, c1.value/value_2 ratio2
                 from crop_data c1
                     inner join
                         (select c2.year c2_yr, c2.area_name c2_country, c2.item_name, c2.unit unit_2, c2.value value_2
                         from crop_data c2
                         where c2.year between ${year1} and ${year2}
                         and c2.unit = 'ha'
                         and c2.item_name = '${itemName}'
                         and c2.area_name = '${area2}')
                     on c1.year = c2_yr and c1.area_name = c2_country
                 where c1.year between ${year1} and ${year2}
                 and c1.unit = 'tonnes'
                 and c1.item_name = '${itemName}'
                 and c1.area_name = '${area2}'
             ) a2
             on a1.a1yr = a2.a2yr`;

            const result = await connection.execute(query);

            try {
                await connection.close();
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log("Encountered an error closing a connection in the connection pool.");
            }
            return result;
            
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }

    }
    fetchQuery3().then(dbRes => {
        res.send(dbRes);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
    })

})
```

From what I've seen on W3 Schools, GfG, YouTube, etc. it seems like this should be working but clearly something is wrong.

Comment: The problem could be in the useEffect and the dependencies variables you passed to it, what those variables do is to re-run the useEffect hook after they've been updated, and as I can see in the code there are several dependency variables (that is what I call them if that's not what they are called), and each of those variables will cause the useEffect hook to re-run after they've been updated, and after calling the useEffect hook the variables gets updated again and they cause the useEffect hook to rerun again and on and on causing infinite recursion

Comment: ...and that overwhelms the server because of the infinite requests being sent to it endlessly

Comment: what you can do is to separate the function from the useEffect and remove those dependency variables from the useEffect, and make the function a standalone useCallback function, then pass the dependency variables to the useCallback instead, but this too might not work well because you'll be calling the function from the useEffect and based on my experience those dependency variables passed to the useCallback function called in the useEffect function will not be updated when they are used inside the useCallback function, it is actually not advisable to use useState variables inside functions...

Comment: ...because of the re-rendering issues, useStates are best used inside the component elements to update the UI or DOM, in this case another method you can use to achieve what you want to achieve is by using form then attach the function to the onsubmit event call of the function, and there are also many ways you can achieve getting data inside the loadQueryInfo() method

Comment: @PaulosAb Thank you. I will look into that. I did have a form setup and was calling those set methods from onChange, but I reverted my code. I guess I'm not even sure that I need use useEffect for what I'm trying to do. I don't want to hit the endpoint unless a button (not currently present) is clicked. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You're welcome, in that case lemme finish my help by explaining further in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way since you have a form

set the states

```js
const [year1, setYear1] = useState("");
const [year2, setYear2] = useState("");
const [area1, setArea1] = useState("");
const [area2, setArea2] = useState("");
const [itemName, setItemName] = useState("");
```

Wrap the loadQueryInfo fn in useCallback like so then pass the variables as dependencies

```js
const loadQueryInfo = React.useCallback(async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from reloading the page
            
            const response = await axios.get(
                `http://localhost:5000/${queryId}`, 
                {params: {
                    area1,
                    area2,
                    year1,
                    year2,
                    itemName
                }});

            const newQueryInfo = response.data.rows.at(0).at(1);
            setQueryInfo([newQueryInfo]);
        }, [area1, area2, itemName, queryId, year1, year2])
```

then set the states in the onchange event of the input fields instead

```
...
<form onSubmit={loadQueryInfo}>
<input type="..." onChange={(e) => setYear1(e.currentTarget.value)} />
//repeat it for other fields
<button type="submit">...</button>
</form>
```

note I didn't test it so I am not sure if `e.currentTarget.value` will return the value of the field, if it doesn't just log `e` in the console and check the right thing, but it should return the value of the field and you can also change the `onChange` event to `onKeyUp` or any other event that suit your purpose

I hope this helps